# TPL Dataflow: How to start the next async action when the current one hasn't finished yet, preserving the execution order?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

Consider the following program, which uses TPL Dataflow. Hence, `ActionBlock` comes from the Dataflow library.

```cs
internal static class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var actionBlock = new ActionBlock<int>(async i =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Started with {i}");
            await DoSomethingAsync(i);
            Console.WriteLine($"Done with {i}");
        });

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            actionBlock.Post(i);
        }

        actionBlock.Complete();
        await actionBlock.Completion;
    }

    private static async Task DoSomethingAsync(int i)
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
    }
}
```

The output of this program is:

```
Started with 0
Done with 0
Started with 1
Done with 1
Started with 2
Done with 2
Started with 3
Done with 3
Started with 4
Done with 4
```

Reason is that the `ActionBlock` only starts processing the next task when the previous asynynchronous task was finished.

How can I force it to start processing the next task, even though the previous wasn't fully finished. `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` isn't an option, as that can mess up the order.

So I'd like the output to be:

```
Started with 0
Started with 1
Started with 2
Started with 3
Started with 4
Done with 0
Done with 1
Done with 2
Done with 3
Done with 4
```

I could get rid of the `async/await` and replace it with `ContinueWith`. But that has two disadvantages:

1. The ActionBlock think it's done with the message immediately. An optional call to `Complete()` would result in the pipeline being completed directly, instead of after the asynchronous action to be completed.
2. I'd like to add a `BoundedCapacity` to limit the amount of messages currently still waiting to be fully finished. But because of 1. this `BoundedCapacity` has no effect.

Comment: Show the `ActionBlock.Post` implementation. Presumably you call the delegate there with await but shouldn't or at least do something else then you do currently. Oh thought it is something implemented by you but its part of the DataFlow stuff.

Comment: @Ralf Good one. I added a bit to clarify that ActionBlock is indeed a given from the Dataflow library.

Comment: You might also want to elaborate on why you need that in a certain order. Parallel and in specific order does not work well together (obviously). The need for that means to me that the multiple delegates started by the ActionBlock would need to know about each other so they can sync execution before running free in parallel afterwards.

Comment: You should probably be using `await actionBlock.SendAsync(i)` instead of `actionBlock.Post(i)` and then evaluating the return value you get. It might not be needed for your use case.

I agree with Ralf. It sounds like you need synchronization of some kind. TPL might not be the best choice for what you're trying to do. Can you give us some more detail?

Comment: Are you interested only in preserving the execution order of the "Started" and "Done" commands, or there are also other intermediate check points inside the `DoSomethingAsync` method that need to be executed in the correct order?

Comment: Regarding the desirable output, is it required to be exactly as shown in the question, with all the "Started" preceding all the "Done", or the order preservation is important only inside each of the groups "Started" and "Done"? So for example if the item 0 completes very quickly (instantaneously), would you like to artificially postpone the command "Done with 0" until all the "Started" commands have been executed?

Comment: @Ralf The order must be guaranteed, because we're interacting with a hardware driver that expects calls in a certain order. But, even though it's busy with a previous request, it does accept already a next request up to a certain amount. And when the first request is done, it can be moved further down the pipeline for some next interaction with that hardware driver. Hope this is clear.

I also thought about using a different approach, but I feel like TPL Dataflow could help us here as we have a complex pipeline where each step has different bounded capacities, could be done in parallel, etc.

Answer (score 1):

In situations like this I would try to remove the requirement that things get processed in order, so that you can process in parallel, and then report sequentially.

```cs
//The transform block can process everything in parallel,
//but by default the inputs and outputs remain ordered
var processStuff = new TransformBlock<int, string>(async i =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Started with {i}");
        await DoSomethingAsync(i);
        return $"Done with {i}";
    }, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5 });

//This action block is your reporting block that uses the results from
//the transform block, and it will be executed in order.
var useStuff = new ActionBlock<string>(result =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    });

//when linking make sure to propagate completion.
processStuff.LinkTo(useStuff, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Posting {0}", i);
    processStuff.Post(i);
}

//mark the top of your pipeline as complete, and that will propagate
//to the end.
processStuff.Complete();
//wait on your last block to finish processing everything.
await useStuff.Completion;
```

output from this code produced the following as an example. Notice that the "started with" statements are not necessarily even in the order of the postings.

> Posting 0
> Posting 1
> Posting 2
> Posting 3
> Posting 4
> Started with 1
> Started with 0
> Started with 2
> Started with 4
> Started with 3
> Done with 0
> Done with 1
> Done with 2
> Done with 3
> Done with 4

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In our case it really needs to be sequential. The block above is an example block, but in our production environment it's part of a large pipeline of blocks that interact with a hardware driver, which expects certain calls in order. Hence, that's where the requirement comes from.

Comment: @Tohnmeister I guess I'm just confused what your requirements are because you can't require parallel and sequential. What I've shown you here is about as close as you'll get where you split it up into parallel steps and sequential steps where the parallel steps order is not guaranteed, but you can't guarantee order otherwise it would be sequential and synchronous, and then the subsequent sequential synchronous step order is guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

I did, in the meantime, find a solution/workaround, by using two blocks, and passing the asynchronous Task from the first block to the next block, where it is waited for synchronously using `.Wait()`.

So, like this:

```cs
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow;

internal static class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var transformBlock = new TransformBlock<int, Task<int>>(async i =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Started with {i}");
            await DoSomethingAsync(i);
            return i;
        });
        var actionBlock = new ActionBlock<Task<int>>(task =>
        {
            task.Wait();
            Console.WriteLine($"Done with {task.Result}");
        });

        transformBlock.LinkTo(actionBlock, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            transformBlock.Post(i);
        }

        transformBlock.Complete();
        await actionBlock.Completion;
    }

    private static Task DoSomethingAsync(int i)
    {
        return Task.Delay(1000);
    }
}}
}
```

This way the first block just considers itself done with a message almost instantly and is able to handle, in order, the next message which calls `DoSomethingAsync` directly, without waiting for the response of the previous call.

Comment: This doesn't allow to configure the `MaxDegreeOfParallelism`. All asynchronous operations are going to be launched immediately, with no limitation whatsoever. Also it doesn't enforce the output requested in the question. A "Done" command might be executed before all the "Started" commands have completed.

Comment: I think I wasn't clear enough in my original question. The DoSomethingAsync in my example is actually just a replacement for a function in production that does guarantee that the first request is always handled first, and returned first.

We don't really need MaxDegreeOfParallelism. We do want some form of parallelism, but in a guaranteed sequential order. I could throttle the whole by putting bounded capacities on both blocks.

Nevertheless, I'm quite new to Dataflow. Feel free to point me to flaws in my reasoning.

Comment: You could consider editing and clarifying the question so that 1. there is a solid base for evaluating your answer and 2. encourage other people to answer the question. All the invariants of the problem should be mentioned, like that *"the production function guarantees that the first request is always handled first"*, and explain exactly what this means because it's not at all obvious. Also that there is no requirement for limiting the concurrency, other than what is naturally imposed by the requirement for guaranteed sequential order.